# EvoPdf: Problem on converting html to image while using baseUrl for external resources

Tags: evopdf, html-to-image

I'm using EvoPdf for converting HTML to an Image (EvoPdf: ConvertHtmlToImageObject). Now I tried to set the baseUrl for using local resources like: in the html I'm using a css link for custom fonts.

imgConverter.ConvertHtmlToImageObject(html, baseUrl: path)
-> the folder contains the css with the @font-faces and the custom font tff's and woff's.

But somehow the it doesn't work. It's like it doesn't even read the baseUrl.
I was trying to use differen baseUrl's, I placed my resources in all different folders of the project but still nothing worked.

Does someone have an idea what I could be doing wrong?
Or even better a working example?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys!
I think I found the issue. I tried to connect to a local drive instead of using the website resources.
The BaseUrl is supposed to be the URL of my website.